# How to set absolute paths with Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova

There are a couple of similar SO questions here about Cordova paths, and that they should always be relative due to the Android and iOS platforms. But my web app takes advantage of the browser's address bar by altering the current path for bookmarking purposes.

For example, you might be on the books page

`mywebsite.com/books`

and then click a book, leading you to

`mywebsite.com/books/some-book`

but the page itself never changed as it is an SPA. However if I used relative paths everywhere, then refreshing on `mywebsite.com/books/some-book` would now try and load assets relative to `/some-book` such as `app.min.js`, etc.

So this relative path system fails both on the browser and on a mobile built cordova app for Android and iOS.

For browser I can maintain the absolute paths I have like `/js/app.min.js` but I was hoping for some solution for Android/iOS/Cordova to use fixed paths as well. When I try `/js/app.min.js` it looks for files in `files:///js/app.min.js` which fails.

I have the power of manipulating the output of my builds quite easily, so if there were some magic path I could inject after my builds for iOS/Android or Cordova in general, such as `file://` or whatever other magic paths there are, then I can solve this problem.

So does absolute pathing exist when building a web app into a mobile app with Cordova?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your paths with

```
 <... src="assets/www/js/some.js">
```